# OWIN 400 invalid_request when using HTTPS on Azure

Tags: azure, https, oauth-2.0, owin

When I deploy [this sample](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) (AuthorizationServer) to the Azure Website and I try to access OAuth controller through HTTPS I get 400 invalid_request. Everything seems to be okay while it's running on localhost. (https as well)

Azure SSL configuration is okay.
(It's the same either with
https:// xxx.azurewebsites.net/OAuth/Authorize?..
or
https:// my.domain.com/OAuth/Authorize?..)

```
AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/OAuth/Authorize");
```

VS AuthorizationServer Properties - i.stack.imgur.com/JpR9H.png

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in ValidateClientRedirectUri? It might be that the redirect uri that you pass to the Authorize endpoint is not validated properly when running in Azure. If context.Validate() is not called in this method you can get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be caused by passing localhost address in redirect. I was testing it with localhost client. Now it is working as expected.